# How to get new column in a data frame Applying Logical operator , if else if

Tags: python, pandas, filter

```
Feature1, Feature2, Feature3, Feature4, TARGET

5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa    
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa        
6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor    
6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor   
6.3,2.5,5.0,1.9,Iris-virginica    
6.5,3.0,5.2,2.0,Iris-virginica
```

how can I work out the target (species) from the relationship of the feature using if else if  or logical operator? For example

If `feature 1` < 5.2 and `feature 2` >3.4 and `feature 3` < 1.5 and `feature 4` <.3 
Then print `iris-setosa`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: use `np.where(cond,if true,if false)`,

```
df['new'] = np.where((df['Feature1'] < 5.2) & (df['Feature2'] > 3.4) & (df['Feature3'] < 1.5) & (df['Feature4'] < .3), "iris-setosa", "")
```

Comment: df['class'] = np.where(((df['heart rate'] > 50) & (df['heart rate'] < 101 )) & ((df['systolic blood pressure'] > 140 & df['systolic blood pressure'] < 160)) & 
((df['dyastolic blood pressure'] > 90 & ['dyastolic blood pressure'] < 100 )) & ((df['temperature'] > 35 & df['temperature'] < 39 )) & 
((df['respiratory rate'] >11 & df ['respiratory rate'] <19)) & ((df['pulse oximetry' > 95] & df['pulse oximetry' < 100] )), "excellent", "critical")              ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your answer. I was trying to put a range of value on that as you can see. But this is showing value error.

Comment: Since you are what look like new to python I would recommend going through a tutorial.And, I would start building conditions one step at a time..

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to subset the dataframe according to your desired `TARGET` column as shown:

```
In [4]: mask = (df['Feature1'] < 5.2) & (df['Feature2'] > 3.4)                 \
   ...:        & (df['Feature3'] < 1.5) & (df['Feature4'] < .3)

In [5]: df.loc[mask, "TARGET"]
Out[5]: 
0    Iris-setosa    
Name: TARGET, dtype: object
```